# Elasticity of subsitution: a redundant calculation?

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

Elasticity of subsitution is a measure of the curvature of an isoquant<sup>1</sup> and can provide us information regarding the nature of the production functions we are dealing with. this is visualized in [Advanced Microeconomic Theory 
by Geoffrey A. Jehle (Author), Philip J. Reny](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0273731912)  (page 130 in the book) as:

[image]

However I wonder, isn't this information regarding the curvature of a isoquant given by the production function? what novel information does the calculation of elasticity of substitution provide us with?

---

<sub>1. I'm aware that elasticity of substitution can also be applied to consumer theory, just that its dominant in producer theory.</sub>

Comment: Graphing would be enough except that you'd have to make a 3-dimensional graph, which is cumbersome.

Comment: @HerrK. 3-dimensions have another problem from what i know, MRTS is a calculation made between only two inputs, so for more than  that i'm not sure what you would do.

Comment: de la Grandville, O. (1997): "Curvature and the Elasticity of Substitution: Straightening It Out," _Journal of Economics,_ 1, pp. 23-34 challenges the notion that "is a measure of the curvature of an isoquant."

Answer (score -1):

Why would one need to graph the function? Isn't any information in the graph already given in the function?

In  a certain sense *all* calculations are redundant as they are mathematical tautologies. Yet these indices make some things more clear, which is obviously useful.

Comment: an interesting comment, but not quite an answer. I'm interested in the novel information that the calculation of elasticity of subsidization provides us with that I cant learn from other calculations.

Comment: @EconJohn I would recommend making your question more clear then. This has nothing to do with drawing graphs.

Comment: @EconJohn Please make your question much more clear. It has not been answered for a month.

Comment: I did the edits.